# Lucene index queries suddenly stop working

Tags: cassandra

We are using Cassandra 4.0 version and their lucen jar plugin have used in the lib folder of Cassandra to run the Lucene index queries but internment the Lucene queries are not working. suddenly stop working then we just drop the index and recreate the index on the same table then it works fine. not able find the root cause for the same issue when we are checking the system logs and find below error. if anyone can help on this.

ERROR [ReadStage-4] 2022-11-25 06:12:29,910 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[ReadStage-4,10,main] java.lang.AssertionError: null

ERROR [ReadStage-1] 2022-11-25 06:12:33,737 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[ReadStage-1,5,main] java.lang.AssertionError: null

Answer (score 1):

Dropping then recreating the index is probably not the right approach since it will only hide the real issue.

Unfortunately, your post is not very descriptive and you haven't provided enough information for anyone to be able to help in a meaningful way.

A friendly note to let you know that describing the issue as "Lucene queries are not working" is not helpful. If you need guidance, see the article on [how to ask a good question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Please supply an example query plus the accompanying table schema to provide context to the issue.

You also haven't specified what level of investigation you've done. The first thing you need to do is review the application logs for the relevant error. Then review the Cassandra logs for errors that correlate to the errors you see in the application logs.

Once you've identified the relevant error, please update your question above with the full error message + full stack trace. It is also important to include the software versions you are running. Cheers!